# Passing ID through form.collection_check_boxes from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** The Product model ID will not enter the UserProduct model.

**Controller:**

**UserProduct Create:**

```
def create
    @user_product = UserProduct.new(user_product_params)
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @user_product.product_id = @product.id
.......
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :sku) do |c| %>
  <%= c.label class:"form-check-inline" do %>
    <%= c.check_box + c.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This shows the Products :sku on the front end, but the ID isn't passing through.

**The error on input is the following:**

`Couldn't find Product without an ID`

**Models:**

**UserProduct:**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

**Product:**

```
....
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_products
....
```

This can't be a nested resource, to my understanding, because the UserProduct model is supposed to pick products from the Product model to then attach to the UserProducts.  So basically, there is a list of products available on the App, and then the User can choose from those products to enter in their UserProduct model.

Anything wrong with my code? How can I pass through the ID from the drop down menu on selection?

Comment: did you define permitted_params in your controller?

Comment: Yes, currently have `params.require(:user_product).permit(:product_id, {product_ids: []})`

Comment: and when i submit the form i get thsi output `..."user_product"=>{"product_id"=>["", "1"]},`

Comment: Using the select helper: `<%= form.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :sku %>` gives me: `..."user_product"=>{"product_id"=>"1"}, ...`

Comment: but OP is using `collection_check_boxes` not `collection_select`

Comment: Hm, so i took out the @product in the create and it worked..... the product.id saved to the database.  must be something with the checkboxes that interfered ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I am the OP :D

Comment: checkboxes passes an array of ids, select passes just 1

Comment: Yep, looks like that was my mistake.  Thanks.  You mentioning the array stuff made me realize i should try using a select helper instead since I only wanted 1 to pass through anyways

Answer (score 0):

`collection_check_boxes` passes an array of ids. If you need only one, try `collection_select` instead.

Comment: It's supposed to be only one product that will go through at any time. so technically, it should be a select  instead of checkboxes.  but I tried your code `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):` with the following passing through: `..., "user_product"=>{"product_id"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"Create User product"}`